# How to send an image and text to a collection in Strapi using Flutter and Dio?

Tags: flutter, post, request, strapi, dio

Title: Creating a POST Request using Flutter and Dio Package for Strapi

I have created a table or collection called "post" in Strapi (headless CMS) with the following fields:

- title: Text type, for the article title
- date: Text type, for the article date
- text: Text type, for the article content
- thumbnail: Media type, with the image of the article

I intend to send a POST request to create a new article in Strapi using Flutter and the Dio package. Can you please provide me with the code that accomplishes this?

Note: I want to receive the thumbnail image from the user through a form.

Thank you.

---

I have made my effort, but unfortunately, I always get a 500 error and my entry is not created in Strapi.